How to understand if a model-algorithm is a machine learning ones or not?
I'm working on thesis to detect change points in a timeseries made of body movements. Im forced to not use any Machine Learning models because my colleague used ML and the professor wants to have a comparison between ML vs change point detection
But i've seen that in CPD you can use supervised approach, so using ML models or unsupervised, for example CUSUM is not ML but pure statistical model but under the unsupervised family.
What i have to do is to make a state of the art of new CPD algorithms-models and apply to the dataset. The problem is. How can i distinguish if this CPD algorithm is ML or not?
For example, i've come across something really fit and similar to my thesis a 2023 challenge for human activity segmentation where they made this challenge to made a state of the art for models in this field. challenge2023
in this challenge there are several state of the art algorithm and one of them is a new algorithm called CLASP
I'm reading the paper but i don't know if this is similar to CUSUM, so it's not machine learning, or it's machine learning. Just by reading the abstract it says

We present ClaSP, a novel, highly accurate,
hyper-parameter-free and domain-agnostic method for TSS. ClaSP hierarchically
splits a TS into two parts. A change point is determined by training a binary TS classifier
for each possible split point and selecting the one split that is best at identifying
subsequences to be from either of the partitions. ClaSP learns its main two modelparameters
from the data using two novel bespoke algorithms

Seems like this clasp learns from the data and also has a training part.
The keywords of this paper is Unsupervised · Self-supervised · Segmentation · Change points
Someone in this kind of field can enlighten me by teach me how to distinguish from ML and not-ML and if this CLASP is ML or not?
